# How to reload a div content automatically

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need that only the content of the div "chat_scroll" are automatically reloaded. I've tried a lot of codes, but the div remains stationary.

At last, I've tried with this:

JS before

```
<script>
function updateDiv()
{
    $( "#chat_scroll" ).load(window.location.href + " #chat_scroll" );
}
</script>
```

JQUERY at the bottom of the file:

```
 <script>
 function myFunction() {
 myVar = setInterval(updateDiv(), 3000);
 }
 </script>
```

Comment: `setInterval(updateDiv(), 3000);` should be `setInterval(updateDiv, 3000);`

Comment: I don't know why the problem isn't fixed. I've setted      setInterval(updateDiv(), 3000);       but nothing. The div remains stationary...

Answer (score 1):

`setInterval` accepts a function as an argument:

```
setInterval(updateDiv, 3000);
```

Note that there's no `()` after `updateDiv`. That would be `calling` the function, and passing its return value to `setInterval`, which is *not* what you're trying to do.

Comment: Hi, thank u for the reply. Now i've:

     setInterval(updateDiv, 3000);

but nothing. The div doesn't reload...

Comment: That is something to do with your `updateDiv` function then. You didn't provide enough information for us to figure out what could be going wrong at this point. You can add a simple `console.log` in `updateDiv`'s body to ensure that the function is being called.

Answer (score -1):

When do you call myFunction()? Try this instead of using myFunction:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    setInterval(function(){
        updateDiv();
    }, 3000);

});
```

Comment: There's no need for the enclosing anonymous function. It only makes code larger and makes code harder to understand.